# Block diagram consideration of a biquad filter

Tags: filter

I would like to know how a transfer function could be easily be translated into a block diagram like this:

(This come from a book on analog biquad filter)

[image]

[image]

Does it exist any method to translate the equation into a block diagram easily?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Going from the block diagram to the TF is a unique solution but, in reverse the solution is not unique.

Comment: @RussellH you might be missing my point. Because there is no unique solution in the direction specified in the question, there is unlikely to be any "*method to translate the equation into a block diagram easily*" without much more information. Or are you hinting at something else that I need to learn or correct in my previous comment?

Comment: @RussellH your comment was to me so, is there something wrong with my comment that you'd like to explain?

Comment: @Andyaka: No sir. Nothing at all. I will fix. My apologies.

Comment: Just pointing out that non-unique block diagrams generated from the same TF are equivialent

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can "translate" a transfer function into a block diagram. However, this is not a purely mathematical method, but instead the result of a theoretical consideration.

A 2nd order low pass can be realized from the series connection of two 1st order low pass sections. However, for a pole quality Qp>0.5 a magnitude boost at the end of the filters pass range is necessary  using the principle of signal feedback.

But you should note that this can result in several alternatives. One variant is shown here in the question with an inverting integrator (can be understood as a lowpass with cutoff frequency wc=0 rad/s) and a damped inverting integrator (identical to an active lowpass of 1st order).

Other variants then result e.g. from the use of one or two non-inverting integrator(s). In this context, it is important to know that for DC the number of minus signs within the feedback loop must always be uneven (1 or 3 or...).

As another alternative, the first block (integrator with resistive feedback) could be replaced by a block which represents a passive RC lowpass. But in this case, another block would be necessary for decoupling purposes (buffer). So - there will be no advantage if compared with the active realisation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,

LvW, So I have to start with 2sd order low pas filter it's two cascaded 1st order integrator, OK, admit that there are negative block (like in the book example), and feedback is needed for the pole quality as you mention, this means the presence of the coefficient -b0 ? but why there is a local feedback on the first stage ? is it the same role as the overall feedback (for Q) ? and why adding a gain (a0) at the end ?

I think I have to read again feedback and system theory, if you have any reference of book/article I will take it

Thanks again for you reply

Comment: @exolune The \$\frac{E_2}{E_1}\$ equation isn't in either of the two standard forms for EE. Also note that for a 2nd order bandpass then the fractional bandwidth matters in deciding whether to separate it into a low pass and a high pass or to combine the two into a single 2nd order stage. Regardless, and to your question, I think Karl Johan Åström & Richard M. Murray 1st or 2nd edition of *"Feedback Systems An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers"* may be useful. [1st edition is free directly from them](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM08/pdf/am08-complete_28Sep12.pdf).

Comment: @exolune, regarding your understanding of the denominator factors: For b1=0 the pole-Q will be infinite and we have an oscillator with a pole pair on the imag. axis. The first integrator block has local feedback because it must work as a 1st-order active lowpass. Two integrators in series with feedback would result in an oscillator (b1=0). Regarding gain (ao): Sometimes a lowpass with a gain>1 is desired. This can be accomplished after filtering, but in most cases the gain is implemented in the 1st block (summing junction). Such an active biquad filter is known as "Tow-Thomas" structure.